# multiply every item in a 2D list by a scalar in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

m is a 2D matrix, something like:

```
[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,1]]
```

`print([i*5 for i in [j for j in m]])` does not work. It repeats items in each row 5 items. I'd like every item to be multiplies by the scalar 5.

Don't want to use numpy. How do I solve this using list comprehensions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,1]]
print([[j*5 for j in i] for i in a])
```

output:

```
[[5, 10, 15], [15, 20, 25], [30, 35, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you require list comprehension, but just to show the option with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

v = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,1]]
vv = np.array(v)

print(vv*5)
# [[ 5 10 15]
#  [15 20 25]
#  [30 35  5]]
```

Comment: This was perfect, thank you. Helps when you don't know/want to all the dimensions and size per dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are *always* one-dimensional. Your "matrix" is just a list of three lists, not a 2D list. Thus, your outer list comprehension needs to generate lists as its elements.

```
[[i*5 for i in row] for row in m]
```

It helps to think of list comprehensions as for loops with accumulators, i.e.

```
output = []
for row in m:
    output.append([i*5 for i in row])
```

Answer (score 0):

[multiply every item in a 2D list by a scalar in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319306/multiply-every-item-in-a-2d-list-by-a-scalar-in-python)

*Installation:* `python3 -m pip install numpy`

```
numpy_array = np.array(L)
scale_factor = 2
result = numpy_array * scale_factor
```